# How to make `npm help` print as plain text?

Tags: npm

The following command will not print the output as plain text, as there are things like `^H` in the output. How to let npm help print the output in plaintext? Thanks.

```
npm help install > /tmp/1.txt
```

Comment: You could pipe it through `col -b`.

Comment: Also, If you want multiple spaces instead of tabs in that output utilize the `-x` switch too. E.g: `npm help install | col -bx > /tmp/1.txt`